# Given $x_1 = a^{1\over k}$ and $x_{n+1} = \left({a\over x_n}\right)^{1\over k}$ prove that $x_n = a^{1-(-k)^{-n} \over k +1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm solving various problems on sequences and here is one I'm stuck with:

> Given $x_1 = a^{1\over k}$ where $a > 0$, and $x_{n+1} = \left({a\over x_n}\right)^{1\over k}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$. Prove that:
>   $$
> x_n = a^{1-(-k)^{-n} \over k +1}
> $$

Everything I've tried so far just gives me some identity. For example:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= \left({a\over x_n}\right)^{1\over k} = \\
&= \frac{a^{1\over k}}{{x_n}^{1\over k}} = \\
&= \frac{x_1}{x_n^{1\over k}}
\end{align}
$$

Now try to express $x_n$:

$$
\begin{align}
x_n^{1\over k} &= \frac{x_1}{x_{n+1}} \iff \\
\iff x_n &= \frac{x_1^k}{x_{n+1}^k}
\end{align}
$$

So this results in $x_n = x_n$ which doesn't show anything. I feel like there might be some smart substitution to translate the problem into some recurrence relation but don't see how.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: how about induction can we solve it using induction?

Comment: @James assuming $x_1$ is the base case what would be the inductive step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_1=a^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
now calculate $x_2$ using $x_{n+1} = \left({a\over x_n}\right)^{1\over k}$

thus $$x_2= (\frac{a}{x_1})^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
thus $$x_2=a^{\frac{1}{k}}*x_1^{\frac{-1}{k}}=a^{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}}$$

now solve for $x_3$ using $x_2$ obtained above

you will get $$x_3=a^{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}}$$
also $$x_4=a^{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{k^4}}$$

hope you are seeing the pattern so 
we can write it for $x_n$

now the problem reduces to summing the series for n(even) $$S_n=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{k^4}+.....-\frac{1}{k^n}$$

Comment: I guess to find the pattern here is not the main problem. As the OP wrote he was not able to prove the formula $$x_n=a^{\frac{1-(-k)^{-n}}{k+1}}$$

Comment: we can easily prove it it is simple series sum in the power of a

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I have mistaken your idea. Yeah this is a quite impressing way to approach to this problem.

Comment: This actually answers the question, after finding a common formula for the sum I got what is required to prove

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may just rewrite the initial relation as
$$
\left(-k\right)^{n+1}\ln (x_{n+1})-\left(-k\right)^{n}\ln (x_{n})=\ln \left[a^{\left(-k\right)^n}\right]
$$ recognizing a telescoping sum then using logarithmic properties.